# Counting vowels using nested loop in python

Tags: python

While self studying nested loop I came across an exercise that I really need help with. The code counts vowels in names from a list and are put into a new list once outer loop finishes. Here is my code:

```
def get_list_of_vowel_count(name_list):

    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"


    count_list = []
    count = 0
    for name in name_list:
        for i in range(len(vowels)):
            if vowels[i] in name:
                count += 1
        count_list += [count]
        count = 0

    return count_list

def main():

    name_list = ["Mirabelle", "John","Kelsey","David","Cindy","Dick","aeeariiiosoisduuus"] 
    vowel_counts = get_list_of_vowel_count(name_list)
    print(vowel_counts)

main()
```

output:

`[3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 5]`

My code doesn't count well.. for instance, vowels in a name `Kelsey` contains 2 `e` but it only counts 1. I think `range(len(vowels))` could be the problem but I am not quite sure.I tried researching on similar topics on SO database but could not find what I was searching for. Please help me write this code correctly. Thank you very much.

ps. using python 3.5

Comment: You only count each vowel once in each `name`, you have the `for` loop and membership test the wrong way around. Consider a `Counter`.

Comment: `if vowels[i] in name:` - you're only counting each vowel once, even if it appears multiple times in the word.

Comment: Thanks i will research more..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if vowels[i] in name:
    count += 1
```

just counts up by one for any number of occurences. Instead you can do

```
count += name.count(vowels[i])
```

Also you can iterate over characters of a string like this:

```
for vowel in vowels:
    # use vowel
```

And there are some more "simplifications" possible in the magical world of python:

```
def get_list_of_vowel_count(name_list):
    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    for name in name_list:
        yield sum([name.count(vowel) for vowel in vowels])
```

or going with itsneo's solution:

```
def get_list_of_vowel_count(name_list):
    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    for name in name_list:
        yield len([c for c in name if c in vowels])
```

`yield` basically just means "append to the list that is returned". It removes the need to manually fill a list and return it later.

And if you want to go crazy for some reason, you can put the outer loop into a list comprehension as well:

```
def get_list_of_vowel_count(name_list):
    return [len([c for c in name if c in "aeiouAEIOU"])
                for name in name_list]
```

Comment: `yield` for a beginner ??!! Sure we need to appreciate people for further learning :d

Comment: Yeah, I am exaggerating using `yield` here, but I believe this is a perfectly fine use, and why not introduce it?

Comment: Thank you very much Felk

Comment: Very neatly written answer that covers various approaches. Kudos

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to go hard on Python. This will be your Pythonic solution

```
for name in name_list:
    print (len([l for l in name if l in "aeiouAEIOU"]))
```

Comment: I hope that one day i'll be able to make list comprehensions like that, without breaking my brain's cpu :D

Comment: Mine started breaking just about now reading all these great answers.. But i will get there.. !!

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_list_of_vowel_count(name_list):
    return [[name.count(v) for v in "aeiouAEIOU"] for name in name_list]
```

Comment: Please note that OP wanted a list that contained the number of occurences of _any_ vowel, but _for each word_

Comment: Thank you, I will look into Counter, join, and using more simplified codes.

Comment: @Felk thanks. I was confused by the output in the question. I reckon it might be a bit overkill to create a `Counter` for each word, so I've made an answer more in line with the others.